# Mouse transparency on undecorated scene

Tags: events, javafx-2, mouse

I have a JavaFX no decorated scene that contain handlers for mouse events such as Moved, Pressed and Dragged to implement widows resizing and moving. Root pane of the window is AnchorPane.

[image: Window when mouse is ready to resize the scene]

The problem is in the following. When I am adding a ScrollPane to the root pane, I can't provide a window resizing for user, because scroll tad is handling mouse events. I also unable to reach this functionality by making upper pane mouse traversable and trying to backward mouse events to upper layer from root pane.

[image: Window when mouse cursor is in window resize mode but use is expecting Scroll tab dragging]

Could you please to help to find a way to solve this problem? It's strongly required to use undecorated window and to use scrollpane areas too.

Thank you!

Root pane code:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="mainPanelRoot" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1020.0"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="com.intellijustice.ui.controllers.IntelliJusticeController">
  <children>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="mainPanel" focusTraversable="true"
            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="32.0"
            AnchorPane.leftAnchor="32.0"
            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="32.0"
            AnchorPane.topAnchor="32.0"
            onKeyPressed="#anchorPaneKeyPressed"
            onMouseMoved="#anchorPaneMouseMoved"
            onMousePressed="#anchorPaneMousePressed"
            onMouseDragged="#anchorPaneMouseDragged">
        <children>
            <ToolBar fx:id="toolBar"
                     AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
                     AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
                     AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"
                     prefHeight="70.0" minHeight="70.0" maxHeight="70.0"
                     onMouseClicked="#toolBarMouseClicked"
                     onMousePressed="#toolBarMousePressed"
                     onMouseDragged="#toolBarMouseDragged">
                <ModuleBar fx:id="moduleBar">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="20.0" right="0.0" bottom="0.0" left="0.0"/>
                    </HBox.margin>
                </ModuleBar>
            </ToolBar>
            <StackPane fx:id="moduleRegion"
                       AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
                       AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
                       AnchorPane.topAnchor="70.0"
                       AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" />
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This root pane is allowed to add any 'model' pane to the moduleRegion. This model is a pane with some content, scroll pane as an example in this question. As shown, root pane contains overridden mouse handlers, the code is too big to include to the question.

Scroll pane is just a HBox pane with a Scroll Pane on it, without any mouse handlers.

Comment: Try to margin scrollpane, so the underlying anchorpane's borders get mouse events. Also it could be helpful if you attached sample code.

Comment: @UlukBiy As I understood you, margin is a way to making a free space on root pane (between border and scroll pane) to make it possible to root pane to receive mouse events, right? I think it's not a solution I am looking for.

I am experimenting with a upper transparent pane that should receive all mouse events and send it to the root layer, probably it will help.

I added some additional info and code.